# If $||f||_p>0$ for some $p$, then $||f||_r>0$ for any $r$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $||f||_p>0$ for some $p$, then $||f||_r>0$ for any $r$. I am not sure if this statement is true but I think I proved it, here is my attempt:

Case 1: 
$r\leq p$ is clear from considering the set $A=\{|f|\leq1\}$ since $|f|^r\geq |f|^p$ on $A$. Thus The integral over $A$ must be $0$. But then $\mu(A^c)>0$ and we are done.

Case 2: This is the part i am not so sure about. You can mirror the previous argument (on $A^c$) and you end up with $\mu(A)>0$. Now I showed that if $\mu(A)>0$ then there is a set of positive measure such that $f$ is uniformly bounded from below which concludes the argument. I used that $\cup \{|f|\geq \frac{1}{n}\}=\{|f|\geq 0\}$ and used continuity of measure.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much simpler. Prove it by contradiction. If the integral of  a non -negative function is $0$ then the function is $0$ almost everywhere (and conversely). So $\|f\|_r=0$ implies $|f|^{r}=0$ almost everywhere; hence $f=0$ almost everywhere  which implies $\|f\|_p=0$.

Comment: Wow, I overcomplicated it sooo much haha. Thank you :P

Comment: A proof is a proof  :P